# Replace words of text area

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, words

I have made a javascript function to replace some words with other words in a text area, but it doesn't work. I have made this:

```
function wordCheck() {
    var text = document.getElementById("eC").value;
    var newText = text.replace(/hello/g, '<b>hello</b>');
    document.getElementById("eC").innerText = newText;
}
```

When I alert the variable newText, the console says that the variable doesn't exist.
Can anyone help me?

Edit:
Now it replace the words, but it replaces it with <b>hello</b>, but I want to have it bold. Is there a solution?

Comment: Note that this will only replace the first `hello` in the text area. If you want to replace all, you have to use a regexp with `/g` modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `<textarea>`, then you need to use `.value` property.

```
document.getElementById("eC").value = newText;
```

And, as mentioned Barmar, `replace()` replaces only first word. To replace all word, you need to use simple regex. Note that I removed quotes. `/g` means global replace.

```
var newText = text.replace(/hello/g, '<b>hello</b>');
```

---

But if you want to really bold your text, you need to use content editable div, not text area:

```
<div id="eC" contenteditable></div>
```

So then you need to access `innerHTML`:

```
function wordCheck() {
    var text = document.getElementById("eC").innerHTML;
    var newText = text.replace(/hello/g, '<b>hello</b>');
    newText = newText.replace(/&lt;b&gt;&lt;b&gt;/g,"&lt;b&gt;");//These two lines are there to prevent <b><b>hello</b></b>
    newText = newText.replace(/&lt;\/b&gt;&lt;\/b&gt;/g,"&lt;/b&gt;");
    document.getElementById("eC").innerHTML = newText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I want to make the text bold but now it displays <b>hello</b> not bold.

Comment: @user3722860: I've updated my answer... the simple answer is that it can't really be done using a simple textarea. Not easily at least. There are already quite a few open, free and proven editors available. I've added some links to my answer. Check those to find whatever best suits your needs

Comment: @user3722860 Edited. Works?

Comment: @nicael: Yes, I did, but why bother developing yet another basic RTE, when there are much more capable tools readily available. CKEditor can be customized to do exactly what the OP wants, without the pains of developing the entire thing. Don't be daft if you can be lazy, that's why I'd strongly suggest using code that is already out there

Comment: I have to use a text area because I have to type in it and then te color change or it change to bold, is this possible?

Comment: @user3722860 But you can type in it.

Comment: @user3722860: You haven't read my updated answer yet, have you: I've linked to a collection of tools that enable you to do all that and more. Some of those tools allow you to design an entire HTML page, so yes: changing font to bold, changing colours and all that is possible

Comment: @nicael: You have to address 1 important issue with your answer, still: if somebody edits the div's content twice (or more), any `hello`'s that have already been replaced with `<b>hello</b>` will be replaced again, giving `<b><b>hello</b></b>`. Also: you're ignoring upper-case strings, which you should take into account, too. You should then also preserve the key-case when replacing. I've dealt with all that in my answer at length. If this is going to be the accepted answer, it should at least be as good as the other answers, IMO

Answer (score 4):

*Update:*
In response to your edit, about your wanting to see the word *"hello"* show up in bold. The short answer to that is: it can't be done. Not in a simple textarea, at least. You're probably looking for something more like an online WYSIWYG editor, or at least a RTE (Richt Text Editor). There are a couple of them out there, [like tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), for example, which is a decent WYSIWYG editor. A list of RTE's and HTML editors [can be found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor).

First off: As others have already pointed out: a textarea element's contents is available through its `value` property, not the `innerText`. You get the contents alright, but you're trying to update it through the wrong property: use `value` in both cases.

If you want to replace *all* occurrences of a string/word/substring, you'll have to resort to using a regular expression, using the `g` modifier. I'd also recommend making the matching case-insensitive, to replace *"hello"*, *"Hello"* and *"HELLO"* all the same:

```
var txtArea = document.querySelector('#eC');
txtArea.value = txtArea.value.replace(/(hello)/gi, '<b>$1</b>');
```

As you can see: I captured the match, and used it in the replacement string, to preserve the caps the user might have used.

But wait, there's more:

What if, for some reason, the input already contains `<b>Hello</b>`, or contains a word containing the string *"hello"* like *"The company is called hellonearth?"* Enter conditional matches (aka lookaround assertions) and word boundaries:

```
txtArea.value = txtArea.value.replace(x.value.replace(/(?!>)\b(hello)\b(?!<)/gi, '<b>$1</b>');
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmyS4/)

How it works:

- `(?!>)`: Only match the rest if it isn't preceded by a `>` char (be more specific, if you want to and use `(?!<b>)`. This is called a negative look-ahead
- `\b`: a word boundary, to make sure we're not matching part of a word
- `(hello)`: match and capture the string literal, provided (as explained above) it is *not* preceded by a `>` and there is a word boundary
- `(?!<)`: same as above, only now we don't want to find a matching `</b>`, so you can replace this with the more specific `(?!<\/b>)`
- `/gi`: modifiers, or flags, that affect the entire pattern: `g` for global (meaning this pattern will be applied to the entire string, not just a single match). The `i` tells the regex engine the pattern is case-`i`nsensitive, ie: `h` matches both the upper and lowercase character.

The replacement string `<b>$1</b>`: when the replacement string contains `$n` substrings, where n is a number, they are treated as *backreferences*. A regex can group matches into various parts, each group has a number, starting with 1, depending on how many groups you have. We're only grouping one part of the pattern, but suppose we wrote:

```
'foobar hello foobar'.replace(/(hel)(lo)/g, '<b>$1-$2</b>');
```

The output would be `"foobar <b>hel-lo</b> foobar"`, because we've split the match up into 2 parts, and added a dash in the replacement string.
I think I'll leave the introduction to `RegExp` at that... even though we've only scratched the surface, I think it's quite clear now just how powerful regex's can be. Put some time and effort into learning more about this fantastic tool, it is well worth it.