# write html code in div and see result instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to setup a div to see the instant result of html by making the div `contenteditable`. Like

```
<div id="edit" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button id="trigger">Apply code</button>
```

Here, `div id="edit"` assumed to be editor and result viewer as well itself. e.g. write code on div then click on "Apply code" button and the result of html code written in div should be appeared within the same div (i.e. div `id="edit"`).

Comment: What exactly should `"Apply code"` do? Interpret the contents as HTML? As JavaScript?

Comment: after trigging to "Apply code" button the html code should be changed into code result

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What kind of "Code" do you expect to see in the div?

Comment: Take a look @this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nfypx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the basic setup of what you're trying to do...

```
<div id='editor' contenteditable></div>
<button id='trigger' value='apply'>
```

And the JS code:

```
document.getElementById('trigger').addEventListener('click', (function(dv)
{
    return function()
    {
        dv.innerHTML = dv.textContent;
    };
}(document.getElementById('editor'))), false);
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYMk9/).
But play around with it, and you'll soon find out that there's a problem with it: Try adding markup tags, and edit the input a second time. That's not going to work as well as you'd hope.
Also check out the resulting DOM, after the user puts in some multi-line input: new divs, paragraphs and what have you are added. You'll have to preserve that markup, using something like:

```
document.querySelector('#editor').addEventListener('click', function()
{
    var currentMarkup = this.innerHTML;
}, false);
```

Then, you'll have to set about sharing that innerHTML with the trigger event handler, and find a way to check if the user changed the actual markup. Have fun with that...

I suggest you use tools that have already been written, tried and tested, instead of setting about building your own.
It'll take you too long, and you'll end up with something that's not even half as capable as the existing editors out there.

Check this related post for details: [Replace words of text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303846/replace-words-of-text-area/24304070#24304070)

Answer (score 2):

**html**

```
<div id="edit" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button id="trigger" onclick="applyCode()">Apply code</button>
```

**js**

```
function applyCode() {
   $('#edit').html($('#edit').html());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div id="editable" contenteditable="true">aaaaaaa</div>
    <br/>
    <button  onclick="texttohtml()">Click to apply Html</button>
    <script>

    function texttohtml()
    {
    var t=$("#editable").text();
    $("#editable").html(t);
    }

    </script>
```